# Python error of class regarding attributes and objects

Tags: python, class, object, compiler-errors, attributes

I have written the following code:

```
class QuizBrain:

  def __init__(self,q_list):
    self.question_number = 0
    self.question_list = q_list
  
  def next_question(self):
    current_question = self.question_list[self.question_number]
    self.question_number += 1
    user_input = input(f"Q.{self.question_number} : {self.current_question} (True/False) : ")
```

But when I create an object of this class and access `object.next_question()` it shows this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 14, in <module>
    quiz.next_question()
  File "/home/runner/quiz-game-start/quiz_brain.py", line 10, in next_question
    user_input = input(f"Q.{self.question_number} : {self.current_question} (True/False) : ")
AttributeError: 'QuizBrain' object has no attribute 'current_question'
```

REPL: https://replit.com/@mrig1134/quiz-game-start#main.py

Comment: It indeed doesn't have that attribute. It's just a local variable.

Answer (score 0):

As the code is written, `current_question` is just a local variable, not a class attribute. Change it to `self.current_question` to turn in into an attribute.

Comment: Can you please see this https://replit.com/@appbrewery/quiz-game-final
Line no 12 of quiz_brain.py